# Creating a animated CSS gradient filled liquid meter

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a meter that fills up that looks like liquid. I found a great Codepen of an example of this.

https://codepen.io/ElaineXu/pen/jAzGAw

However when I try to change the fill to a gradient it won't work because the front wave slides to the left so won't have the correct gradient and looses the effect.

https://codepen.io/ptimson/pen/JjGNGKm

**HTML**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="wave">
    <path d="M420,20c21.5-0.4,38.8-2.5,51.1-4.5c13.4-2.2,26.5-5.2,27.3-5.4C514,6.5,518,4.7,528.5,2.7c7.1-1.3,17.9-2.8,31.5-2.7c0,0,0,0,0,0v20H420z"></path>
    <path d="M420,20c-21.5-0.4-38.8-2.5-51.1-4.5c-13.4-2.2-26.5-5.2-27.3-5.4C326,6.5,322,4.7,311.5,2.7C304.3,1.4,293.6-0.1,280,0c0,0,0,0,0,0v20H420z"></path>
    <path d="M140,20c21.5-0.4,38.8-2.5,51.1-4.5c13.4-2.2,26.5-5.2,27.3-5.4C234,6.5,238,4.7,248.5,2.7c7.1-1.3,17.9-2.8,31.5-2.7c0,0,0,0,0,0v20H140z"></path>
    <path d="M140,20c-21.5-0.4-38.8-2.5-51.1-4.5c-13.4-2.2-26.5-5.2-27.3-5.4C46,6.5,42,4.7,31.5,2.7C24.3,1.4,13.6-0.1,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l0,20H140z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<div class="box">
  <div class="percent">
    <div class="percentNum" id="count">0</div>
    <div class="percentB">%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="water" class="water">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 560 20" class="water_wave water_wave_back">
      <use xlink:href="#wave"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 560 20" class="water_wave water_wave_front">
      <use xlink:href="#wave"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}
$bgColor:#020438;
$boxColor:#020438;
$waterFColor: pink;
$waterBColor:#C7EEFF;

body {
  background:$bgColor;
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.box{
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: $boxColor;
  border-radius:100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
  .percent{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center; 
    color:#fff;
    font-size:64px;
  } 
  .water{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform:translate(0,100%);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(235,59,171,1) 0%, rgba(236,89,214,1) 15%, rgba(219,91,166,1) 25%, rgba(120,86,211,1) 100%);
    transition: all .3s;
    &_wave{
      width: 200%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      &_back {
        right: 0;
        fill: $waterBColor;
        animation: wave-back 1.4s infinite linear;
      }
      &_front {
        left: 0;
        fill: $waterFColor;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        animation: wave-front .7s infinite linear;
      }
    }
  }
}
@keyframes wave-front {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-back {
  100% {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
var cnt=document.getElementById("count"); 
var water=document.getElementById("water");
var percent=cnt.innerText;
var interval;
interval=setInterval(function(){ 
  percent++; 
  cnt.innerHTML = percent; 
  water.style.transform='translate(0'+','+(100-percent)+'%)';
  if(percent==100){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},60);
```

Any ideas how I could fill the SVG with a moving gradient / create some kind of mask to make this look correct?

Looks like they do it here https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Liquid-Loading-Indicator-Plugin-jQuery-createWaterBall/

Comment: Just realised I could extend the front wave down to fill the rest of the meter. The issue with this is that the gradient of the meter would keep scrolling.

Comment: I would make the gradients fill non-animated objects in the SVG and then use the wave paths as masks to "reveal" the gradient. If I have time today I'll try to create an example for you.

Comment: Thanks @BryceHowitson yes some kind of mask seems to be the way to go